# Error in Custom Adapter ListView in getView() Method

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm facing a very weird behavior in my application.
The problem is that I have a navigation drawer in my activity, but I need to show to different ListView in the navigation drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/lb_dashboard_menu"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/menu_gateways"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@color/background_clear" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv_menu_gateway"
        android:minHeight="90dp"
        android:background="@color/background_accent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/menu_options"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@color/background_clear"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_menu_options"
        android:background="@color/background_accent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see in the code above, the problem is that when I'm loading the Adapter for the first ListView I was trying to debugged it and the method `getView()` is repeating indefinitely without no apparently reason.

In the second ListView I'm sure I'm passing a list of 5 items, but at debugg time I found that the position is always 0.
That's why I only get the first item of the list in the Activity.

```
public class ListGatewayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected List<Device> devices;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;
    AppManager manager;

    public ListGatewayAdapter(Activity activity, List<Device> devices){
        this.devices = devices;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        manager = AppManager.getManager(activity.getApplication());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return devices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Device getItem(int position) {
        return devices.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if(convertView == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gateway_cell, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lb_gateway_name);
        TextView number = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lb_gateway_number);
        ImageView status = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.im_gateway_active);
        Device device = getItem(position);
        name.setText(device.getDeviceName());
        number.setText(device.getDeviceNumber());
        String lastDeviceConnected = manager.RetrieveSharedLastDeviceConnect();
        if(lastDeviceConnected != null){
            if(lastDeviceConnected.equals(device.getDeviceNumber()) ) {
                status.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 255));
            }else{
                status.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Above is the code for the first adapter, the second one it is very similar to this one.

I hope some could help me to find a solution for this problem.

**Update** I noted in the monitor I got this:

```
10-29 15:23:07.330 8785-8785/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ListView{11445886 VFED.VC. .F....ID 0,540-888,810 #7f0c007c app:id/lv_menu_gateway} during layout: running second layout pass
10-29 15:23:07.370 8785-8785/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ListView{11445886 VFED.VC. ........ 0,540-888,810 #7f0c007c app:id/lv_menu_gateway} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
```

Comment: set the fix height for your listview, for ex 200dp and test it again

Comment: you may want to add a viewholder to avoid frequent calls to the findViewById method. Besides I'd like to see how you initialize the list and the related adapter

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Leon_SFS this solve the problem with the second ListView, but what about the problem that i found in the Android Monitor?

Comment: Thank you @Sindico I'm loading the list manually

Comment: When do you get that error int he console? When you inflate some view?

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera your welcome, i think the request layout calls twice, check imageView scale type in listview, maybe its scale image and cause more requestLayout

Comment: @Leon_SFS thank you, I have an two images in the cell, and this is the code: `<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/im_gateway_active"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done_18dp" />`

Comment: What is the scale type please?

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera check this link for scaleType = http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Leon_SFS, you help me a lot, I'm going to check the link and get solve this. Thanks again

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera your welcome, for listView make sure it,s have space to show row, unless its did'nt call the getView method, for problem in monitor log i check it and if i find any solution come back here, good luck

Comment: @Leon_SFS you are the best, thank you so much for your help. I owe you one!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the layout width and height of the first ListView to "match_parent".